# How do I remove certain parts from a string in a dataset in python?

Tags: python, sql, dataset, trim, strip

I have a data set that has a code and then a name with a code, and there multiple codes and multiple names example:

### |CODE|NAME|

### |TN  |Tobey JacobsTN|

### |GD  |Lars OwensGD|

### |YO  |Mark SmithYO|

### |BM  |John SawyerBM|

etc...

How would I take the code out and just leave the name using python?

Comment: What is your expected output and is the input data given as a string or something else?

Comment: So  I am trying to separate for example Tobey Jacobs from :TN, so I end up with a dataset that has the code column as is and then has the modified name column which just contains the name.

Comment: What type of object is the input data set given as?

Comment: It is given as nvarchar (although on python it just says object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    strings = [
        '|CODE|NAME|',
        '|TN |Tobey JacobsTN|',
        '|GD |Lars OwensGD|',
        '|YO |Mark SmithYO|',
        '|BM |John SawyerBM|'
    ]
    records = [[field.rstrip(' ') for field in s.split('|')[1:-1]] for s in strings][1:]
    print("records:"); [print(x) for x in records]
    names = [name[:-len(code)] for code, name in records]
    print("names:"); [print(x) for x in names]
```

... which gives the following output:

```
records:
['TN', 'Tobey JacobsTN']
['GD', 'Lars OwensGD']
['YO', 'Mark SmithYO']
['BM', 'John SawyerBM']
names:
Tobey Jacobs
Lars Owens
Mark Smith
John Sawyer
```